# Storing commit log in an ephemeral disk?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

In EC2, if stopped and started, or rebooted, the data on the ephemeral disk will be erased.

The question is, is it a good idea to put the commitlog on an ephemeral disk?

What if the instance get rebooted and lost the commitlog, what will happen?
I already have replication factor to 2, using `NetworkTopologyStrategy` that is availability zone aware.

Please advice

Comment: *"...or rebooted..."* is **not correct**.  The ephemeral disk contents do survive across reboots, but not stop/start. [*"The data in an instance store persists only during the lifetime of its associated instance. If an instance reboots (intentionally or unintentionally), data in the instance store persists."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#instance-store-lifetime)

Comment: But, isn't the instance get stopped before getting rebooted?

Comment: No. Rebooting an EC2 instance is like pressing control-alt-delete.  Whether you reboot from the EC2 console, or the API (including the SDKs), or `sudo reboot`, the instance remains on the same physical host and retains its ephemeral disks intact.  Stopping an instance removes it from its physical host at AWS and, upon starting it again, it's deployed to a new physical host with its EBS volumes and network interfaces automatically moved over, but with new empty ephemeral disks.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html#lifecycle-differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commitlog is a fundamental part of the C* durable write architecture. A brief look at the [Cassandra Write Path](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html) shows that every write goes to a memtable and to the commitlog. The latter is the way of C* to survive a crash. If you put the commitlog on ephemeral disks that vanishes on a system crash you are defeating the durable writes and you're going to lose data on the node. RF will help you to ensure that data in the node will be restored, but will expose you to the crash of the second machine.

Definitely, that's a thing I would avoid, EC2 VMs gets rebooted too often...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, so, I will be using an EBS

Comment: Do you think storage performance for commit log needs high performance that data storage needs?

Comment: @simo if you use small writes I suggest to put commitlog on an high performance IOPS-wise device. A plain HDD otherwise.

Comment: what about putting the commitlog and db data on the same high performance IOPS disk?

Comment: You'll certainly perform better, but if it's worth it depends on the read/writes ratio of your workload.

Comment: writing is much more than reading.. so, if reading got more, then, separate SSD for commitlog is better?

Comment: A simple comment would not be enough to explain my ideas. Create another SO question, I'll be glad to provide my ideas there.

Comment: would you like to add your thoughts there? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084687/commitlog-storage-vs-read-write-ratio

Comment: yep sorry I was quite busy.I will.