# Dedicated commitlog storage vs Read/Write ratio?

Tags: cassandra

As we are using SSD disks to provide storage for our cluster on servers with 30 GB of memory.

There is an argument about the commitlog directory, whether to dedicate an individual disk or having it on the same data disk.

As we already using SSD disks, performance should be fine having both commitlogs and data on the same disk, as there is no mechanical moving head for writing.

However, there is another factor, that is the read/write ratio. How would such a ratio affect the performance of writing or reading when we have both commitlogs and data on the same disk?

Using SSD, when would it become important to dedicate a high performance disk for the commitlog directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dedicated commitlog device usually makes a lot of sense when you have HDDs, but is less obvious if you're using SSDs.

Even if you asked only if it makes sense with SSDs setups, I will try to give some general hints about the subject, primarily based on my understandings and my own experience. I admit the focus is probably too much on HDDs, but HDDs allow a deep insight on how Cassandra stuff works and why backing a commitlog/data directory with an SSD can be a life saver.

---

### Background: IOPS and OPS are not the same thing.

I will start from a (very) far point: Device Performance. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS)'s a start-point lecture about storage device performances *in general*. Even if the article's neutrality is under [discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:IOPS#.23), it can provide some insights about the general metrics and performance you can expect from some systems. Of course, your mileage may vary, depending on what device (type/brand/model etc...) and how much stress (intended as type of workload) you put on the device, but I think it is a good starting point for our discussion here.

The reason I prefer to start from IOPS is because it is the very starting point for understanding storage performance. The C* literature speaks about OPS, Operations Per Second, because people usually don't think in terms of IOPS, especially when looking at stats. This really hides a lot of details, the operation *size* for starters.

A Cassandra Operation usually consists of multiple IOPS. Cassandra documentation usually refers to spinning disks (even if SSDs are referenced too), clearly states what happens when performing reads/writes, and people tend to ignore the fact that when their software stack (that spans from up the application down to Cassandra and its data files on the storage) hit the disks the performance decreases by a *huge* amount just because they have failed to recognize a random workload, and even if "Cassandra is an high-performance etc... etc.. etc...".

As an example, looking at the picture in the [read path](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutReads.html) documentation, you can clearly see what data structures are in memory/on disk, and how the SSTable data is accessed. Further, the *row cache* paragraph says:

> ... If row cache is enabled, desired partition data is read from the row cache, potentially saving **two seeks** to disk for the data...

And here's where the catch starts: these **two seeks** are potentially saved from **Cassandra's point of view**. This simply means that Cassandra won't make **two** requests to the storage system: it will avoid to request the *partition index*, and the *data* because everything is already in RAM, but it doesn't really translates to "the storage system will save **two** IO operations". Indeed, how (generic) data is retrieved from the storage device is a **very** different thing, and of course depends on how the files are layed-out on the disk itself: are you using EXT4, XFS, or what? Assuming no cache is available (eg for very big data set sizes you can't really cache everything...), **looking for a file is IOPS consuming**, and this tends to *amplify* the **potentially saved seeks** when you have data in RAM, and tends to *amplify* the penalty you *perceive* when your data is not.

---

### You can't escape physics: HDDs pay some taxes, SSDs no.

As you already know, the main "problem" (performance-wise) of HDDs is the *average seek time*, that is the time the HDD needs to wait on average in order to have *a target sector* under the heads. Once the sector is under the heads, if the system have to read a bunch of sequential bits everything is smooth and the throughput is proportional to the rotational speed of the HDD (to be precise to the *tangential* speed of the platters under the head, which depends also on the *track* etc...).

In other terms, HDDs have an average fixed performance tax (the *average seek time*), and everything after is almost "free". If an application requests a bunch of sectors that are not "contiguous" (from the disk point of view, eg a fragmented file is splitted across multiple sectors, but an application can't really know this), the disk will have to wait the *average seek time* on average multiple times, and this fixed tax influences its maximum throughput.

The strongest argument about storage is: **every device have its own maximum magic average IOPS number**. This number express the number of **random** IOPS the device can perform. You can't force an HDD to have more IOPS on average, it's a physical problem. The OS is usually smart enough to "enqueue" sector requests in the attempt to reduce the seek times, eg ordering by ascending requested sector number (trying to exploit some sequential operations), but nothing will save the performances from a random IO workload. You have **X** allotted available IOPS and must face your problems with that. No matter what.

---

### You need to take advantage of the allotted IOPS of your device, and you must be wise on how you use them.

Suppose you have an HDD that maxes out at 100 IOPS on average. If your application performs a bunch of small (say 4KB) file reads, you have an application that performs 100 * 4KB reads every second: the throughput will be around 400KB/s (unless some caching is involved, and in that case the cache saved you precious IOPS). Astonishing. This is simply because you keep paying the *seek time* multiple times. If you change your access pattern to something that reads 16MB (contiguous) files, you get an higher throughput because you won't pay the *seek time* so much, you are *exploiting a sequential pattern*. What changes under the hood is the **Request Size** of each operation.

Now an interesting question is: how are "IOPS" and "Request Size" related to? Does **one** request size of 16MB can be considered **one** IOPS? And what about a 128MB request size? This is indeed a good question. At lower level, the **Request Size** spans from 512 bytes (the minimum sector size) to 128KB (32*4K sectors in one request). If the operation has small size, its **transfer time**, the time the disk needs to fetch the data, is also small. Higher request sizes have higher transfer times obviously. However, if you are able to perform 100 4KB IOPS, you will probably be able to perform around 80 IOPS @8KB. The relation can't be linear, because the transfer time depends on the rotational speed of the disks *only* (the transfer time is negligible compared to the seek time), and since you are actually reading from two adjacent sectors, you'll hit the *seek time* penalty once per request. This translates to a throughput of around 400KB/s for 4K requests and 1.6MB/s for 8K requests. And so on.... The larger the request size, the longer it takes to transfer data, the lesser IOPS you have, the higher throughput you have. (These are *random* numbers, pun intended, no measurements done! Just to let you understand. I however think they are in the ballpark).

SSDs don't suffer mechanical penalties and that's why they are capable of performing much better than HDDs. They have much more IOPS, and their limits come from the onboard electronics, bus connection etc.... Having an higher IOPS device is a big plus, these can be consumed by applications that are **not IOPS friendly**, and the user won't notice that the applications suck. However, with SSDs, the Request Size linearly influences the number of IOPS you can perform. When you look at some device that have 100k IOPS, these are usually referred at 4K. You'll be able to perform only 6.2k requests if you perform 64K requests.

---

### Why Cassandra has a such good read performances even with HDDs then?

Speaking from a single node point of view (because given the performance of a cluster Cassandra scales linearly with the number of nodes in the cluster), the problem lies in the question itself. This is only true if you model your data in this particular way:

1. You must fetch all your data with one query only.
2. Your data must be ordered.
3. If you can't fetch your data with one data, denormalize in order to retrieve it with one query only.
4. You fetch a relative good amount of data on every read

These are well-known Cassandra modeling rules, but the key point is that these rules do really have a reason to be applied IOPS-wise. Indeed, these rules allow Cassandra to:

1. Be a super fast database because it will just require the *partition index* and the *SSTable* offset index of the data: **two IOPS** in the best case, **much more IOPS** in the worst case.
2. Be a super fast database because it will exploit the sequential capabilities of the HDDs and will not stress the IO subsystem by issuing other IO (random) seeks.
3. Be a super fast database because it will just fetch more data like the point number 1.
4. Be a super fast database because it will exploit *longer* the sequential capabilities of the HDDs.

In other terms, following these basic data modeling rules allows Cassandra to be IOPS friendly when reading data back.

What happens if you screw-up your data model? Cassandra won't be IOPS friendly, and as a consequence the performances will be predictably horrible. Unless you use an SSD, which has greater IOPS and then you won't notice slowness too much.

What happens if you read/write a small amount of data (eg due to misconfigured flush sizes, small commit log etc...)? Cassandra won't be IOPS friendly, and as a consequence the performances will be predictably horrible. Unless you use an SSD, which has greater IOPS and then you won't notice slowness too much.

---

### How a read/write ratio pattern can influence performance in a Cassandra node?

Cassandra is a complex system, with different components that interact each other. I will try to explain from my point of view what are the main points when you put everything on one device only.

Writes/Deletes/Updates in Cassandra are fast because they are simply append-only writes to the CommitLog device. Reads, on the contrary, can be very IOPS consuming. When both CommitLog and Data are on the same physical disk (either HDD or SSD), the read/write paths interact, and they both consume IOPS.

Two important questions are:

1. How many IOPS a read (using the read path) consumes?
2. How many IOPS a write consumes?

These are important question because you have to remember that your device can perform at most **X** IOPS, and your system will have to split these **X** IOPS among these operations.

It is quite difficult to answer to the "read" question because, when you request some data, Cassandra needs to locate all the SSTables needed to satisfy the request. Assuming a very big dataset size, where caching is not effective, this imply that the Cassandra read path can be very IOPS hungry. Indeed, if your data is spread into 3 different SSTables, Cassandra will have to locate all of them, and for each SSTable will follow the read path: will read the *partition index*, and then will read the data in the SSTable. These are **at least** two IOPS, because if your filesystem is not "collaborative" enough, locating a file and/or pointing at a file offset could require some more IOPS. In the end, in this example Cassandra is consuming **at least** six IOPS per read.

Answering the "write" question is also tricky, because compactions and flushes can be triggered. They will consume a lot of IOPS. Flushes are easy to understand: they write data from memtables to disk with a sequential pattern. Instead, compactions read data back from different SSTables on disk, and while reading the tables they flush the result out to a new disk file. This is a mixed read/write pattern, and on HDDs this is very disruptive, because will force the disk to perform multiple seeks.

---

### Mixing percentages: TL;DR

If you have a R/W ratio of 95% reads and 5% writes, having a separate CommitLog device can be a waste of resources, because writes will hardly impact your read performances, and you write so rarely that write performance may be considered not critical.

If you have a R/W ratio of 5% reads and 95% writes, having a separate CommitLog device can be again a waste of resources, because reads will hardly impact your write performances, and your read performances will hardly suffer from a bunch of sequential appends on the commitlog.

And finally, if you have a R/W ratio of 50% reads and 50% writes, having a separate CommitLog device is NOT a waste of resources, because every write performed on the CommitLog device won't produce **at least two IOPS** on the data drive (one for writing, and one for going back to read).

Please note that I didn't mention compactions, because independently on your workload, when compaction triggers in, your workload will be disrupted by mixed read/write background operations on different files (consuming disk IOPS all the way), and you will suffer both on reads and writes.

All this should be clear enough for HDDs because you run out of IOPS very fast, and when you do you notice it immediately. On SSDs, however, you don't run out of IOPS *that* fast, but you could do if your data consists of a lot small data rows.

The reality is that getting out of IOPS on an SSD is very hard because you'll get out (by a far amount) of CPU resources, But once you do you will see your performance slowly decrease. The effect however won't be such dramatic as in the cases of HDDs. As an example, if you have a 100 IOPS HDD and you run-out of IOPS by trying to issue 500 random IO stuff, you cleary get a penalty. By calling this penalty **P**, if you have an SSD with 100k IOPS, to get the same penalty **P** you should issue 500k IOPS, which can be very difficult to do without exhausting CPU or RAM.

In general, when you run out of some type of resource in your system, you need to increase its quantity. The most important thing (to me) is not to run out of IOPS in the "Data" part of your Cassandra cluster. In the case of SSDs IOPS, it's rare enough that you'll get the limit. You'll burn your CPU well before I think. But you will if you don't tune your system, or if your workload put **too much** stress on the disk subsystem (eg Leveled Compaction). I'd suggest to put an ordinary HDD instead of an high performance SSD for the commitlog, saving money. But if you have a lot of very small commitlog flushes an SSD is a completely life saver, because your writers won't suffer the latency of HDDs.

Finally, in my opition, you should go in pre-production with some sort of real data, and check your IOPS requirements. If you have enough room to put the SSD there don't worry. Go and save money. If your system gets too much pressure due to compaction then having a separate device is suggested. Analyze your commitlog pattern, and if its not IOPS demanding put it on a separate disk. Moreover, if you have a virtual environment you can provision a relatively small commitlog device regardless of other factors. It won't rise the cost of your solution too much.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! do you have a Twitter account or other social network where you write your ideas or experiences?

Answer (score 1):

The actual numbers will depend highly on the type of workload you have the configuration you have etc. You can have a look at Netflix tech blog posts for ballpark numbers, e.g. [#1](http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/07/benchmarking-high-performance-io-with.html), [#2](http://techblog.netflix.com/2011/11/benchmarking-cassandra-scalability-on.html).

[image: Per node throughput]

Dedicating a disk for commitlog directory is a sort of scale up strategy. Cassandra works well with scale out approach. You just add more nodes into the cluster to spread the load - 2nd from the linked articles has a nice graph showing near linear scalability.

[image: Scalability]

Comment: Thanks, is there a formula to calculate write/read capacity per second for the cluster with respect to added nodes?

Comment: No, I don't have that and I doubt there is a one somewhere. It depends on your application a lot